# Alt-tab from fullscreen SDL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, fullscreen, alt-tab

When I run a fullscreen window (C++ with SDL using the `SDL_FULLSCREEN` flag), alt-tab has no effect. Researching it, I only found posts of people having problems with it. Is there a way to do it consistently across different machines? (I'm running Ubuntu now, but I'd like portability) Does `OpenGL` handle this better? (considering switching)

Comment: OpenGL will not create windows for you, but libraries like SDL, GLUT or QT do. You'll need to use one of those even if you choose to draw graphics with OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SDL likes to `XGrabKeyboard()` when fullscreened on X11.  This tends to lock out your window manager's hotkeys.

Fix SDL or fix your window manager.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, are you saying that there's no good way to do this with SDL?

Comment: You could handle the hotkey yourself, maybe just drop out of fullscreen if you're only having this problem on X.  Or you could release the grab, or stay in windowed mode and make a no-border window that exactly matches the screen size.  [Here's where I'm looking](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/wm.html).